# Programatically Manipulating WCF Binding, Not Having Effect

Tags: c#, wcf

I have run into the dreaded

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

error. No problem, I know you have to change the attributes on the web.config for the client and server to increase it up. I am creating my client in code however, and I am trying to manipulate these properties in kind.

Here I am creating the client, and assigning it to session. I will later call it through a class level `_client` field.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;

binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_Test";
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(wcfUrl);

HttpContext.Current.Session["Client"] = new TestClient(binding, endpointAddress);
```

I change the binding in code, and I could see in a watch these values are indeed taking effect. The _client in the below is the `TestClient` that was created before and stored in `Session`. However, the error persists. Is there another property I am missing?

```
Binding binding =  _client.Endpoint.Binding;           
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max, null);
binding.GetType().GetProperty("TransferMode").SetValue(binding, TransferMode.Streamed, null);        
binding.GetType().GetProperty("MaxBufferPoolSize").SetValue(binding, int.MaxValue, null);
binding.GetType().GetProperty("MaxBufferSize").SetValue(binding, int.MaxValue, null);
binding.GetType().GetProperty("MaxReceivedMessageSize").SetValue(binding, int.MaxValue, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both client and server binding would need

```
maxReceivedMessageSize
```

Setting your values to Max is a bad idea. You really want to try and limit that down to what you believe your usage is. Unless you really need 2gb file transfers and the server can handle that.